# UIWebview Rotation issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am creating a UIWebView, with is rendered to use only 60% of the size of the screen ( width and height ). Everything is working fine in portrait mode ( even if the image I load is bigger than the screen, I use some methods to fit the image inside its frame ).
The problem is that when I turn to landscape mode, it all become a huge mess. Is there any specific method to use that resize de UIWebview when it is on the landscape mode? Thanks in advance.

This is How I am creating the webview :

UIWebView *webview = self.model.webview;
                webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

```
webview.delegate = self;
webview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _adView.frame.size.width * _scale, _adView.frame.size.height * _scale);
webview.center = CGPointMake(_adView.frame.size.width/2, _adView.frame.size.height/2);
webview.opaque = NO;
webview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
webview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
if ([webview respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollView)]) {
    UIScrollView *scrollView = webview.scrollView;
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = NO;
    scrollView.bounces = NO;
}
[self addView:webview];
```

Comment: Please post provide a minimal example in code of your implementation - it's impossible to debug without it. And are you using AutoLayout?